# How do I allow user to run a R script without making a website or web application?

Tags: r, data-product

I have data & a R script that creates a report from the data. I can't expose the data to internet. Also, I cant expose my script to internet / user. But I would like to eliminate myself from the work, and allow couple of users (yeah, only three users that use this script to generate reports, but they do it weekly) to run the script and generate report for them. 
I would like the community to suggest me how I can achieve this. Any information helps.

Comment: This is an IT question, not a data science question so is off-topic here.

Comment: you can create a cron job that runs your script and automatically sends an email to the users

Answer (score 0):

If you work on Linux, you may create a script that loads data and runs R inside and give the users the access to execute the main script. I do not know the details but this may be a possible solution.